# I'm stuck at 1200 elo, how do I get higher?

Tags: league-of-legends

My problem is that im stuck at 1200 elo, I can't get any higher.
Sometimes I win, but I get a lot of trollers in my game.

Does anyone know how to get higher?

Comment: This question is really vague, and lacking in details, and in it's current state will be closed. You should edit your question to include more details about what specific problems you're having.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping from League of Legends Elo Hell](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19184/escaping-from-league-of-legends-elo-hell)

Answer (score 1):

There is no real trick to get out of 1200 elo. In my opinion it's probly the worst elo u can be in. However there are some things that might help you in getting out of there. First of all u cannot be another troll. If you troll then expect people to troll you. Always try to communicate with ur team, pick whats needed and dont go 'mid or feed'. Dont be offensive, try to make the atmosphere in ur team as good as possible, if some1 is annoying just ignore him. Dont try to make stupid people understand how stupid they are. They are too stupid to do it. What also helped me a lot, was learning how to play one single champion as well as possible (in my case it was graves). Just play lots of normal games as this champion first and then go rankeds. Ofc be prepared to play any other role aswell, be it support, jungle or solo top. U need to be able to support or team in any situation.

U can also try using this low-mid elo stompers like shaco, lb, kassadin etc. If u play them well enough u might have a bit easier time trying to get out of 'elo hell'.

Hope that was somewhat helpful :).

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do (except playing decently of course) is picking roles which can carry - and by this I don't mean AD Carry. The problem is that even if youre a good AD Carry, most random teammates dont bother to protect you.

So if you really want to make the difference you need to play some kind of Tank or Tanky DPS/Bruiser. A fed Jax/Olaf/Riven for example often makes the difference.

Answer (score 0):

there really is no way to guarantee raising your elo or everyone would be sitting at 2000+.

with that being said what you want to do is be able to win your lane and hope that your team doesnt feed that much.  also playing hyper carries and getting fed, assuming you are skilled enough to crush the other lane and feed on them, is a good way to snow ball to victory.  an other way is to just out play the other team, ever if your team is beat in every lane you may still win in teamfights and those are more important then farming in the laning phase but it will be more difficult.  one more thing never give up and try to go in with a positive attitude.  one team fight can win you the game and starting out with a negative attitude will only cause your game play to suffer and will end with you raging at your team.

hope this has helped.

ps. you can get out of elo hell playing any role, i made it to 1600's playing mostly supports.

Answer (score 0):

you gonna have trolls in any kind of game wich sucks but you have to deal with it.
the way i got up higher is play 1 role and stick with that as much as possible.
when you choose a role pick a few strong champs you like, 2-3 champs max and just play.

hope it works out for you :D